# Design a correct microservices architecture with data relations

Tags: database, api, microservices, web-services

I just started thinking about building a microservices architecture for learning purposes.
I understood that microservices are split, and they should be independent, even when storing data, but what is the real application of it?
Most data isn't independent, and is relational in some way, even when using non-relational databases.

My starting idea is a basic app where someone can watch something, let's say a TV serie, have an account with a profile, and can comment and like that TV serie.

The idea is to divide everything in the two following services:

- User service, which basically means authentication and storing users data;
- TV series service, which stores TV series data, episodes, links and other blah blah;
- Streaming service, which handles video streaming, but let's not talk about it.

Obviously, for a correct independent microservices architecture pattern, we should split databases.

Now, my questions are:

1. Let's say we use JWT for authentication, so it's stateless, and TV series needs authentication to perform some actions. Should the TV series service implement authentication too? Should they check for your JWT token, or should they call the User service to handle authentication?
2. Where should you then store things that a user does - like comments, and likes, if there is a relation between the two databases? If having a single shared database is an anti-pattern, and calling a microservice from another one is an antipattern too, how should you handle a comment? In what database should you store it? And then, how would you do a query which gets "all comments of a specific user" if you can't join or aggregate data between databases, because they're split? Is manual aggregation worth doing?
3. Would this approach benefit of an API gateway? I can't understand why and what API gateways are. Though I understood that, someway, they can help joining responses of two microservices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so what you would often do in such a situation is introduction of API Gateway.
The UI doesn't want to know that there are 3 services that it needs to talk to. There are 3 of them now. Perhaps tomorrow the backend team will decide to split one of them into 2. That's up for them to decide but this should not need any updates in the UI.
So what you have is API Gateway. The UI only ever talks to API gateway. Now the API Gateway has a few goals:

1. validate the body of the request. if the body is fucked up, it doesn't make much sense to propagate it any further.
2. decode JWT. Again, if JWT is missing or is invalid, it doesn't make much sense to propagate the request any further. In the same time, all the services behind the api gateway will be interested in who made the request, so it would be beneficial for API Gateway to forward the decoded JWT to them in one way or another. But yes. This will probably call the user/authentication service. Usually this is pretty simple if you use some of-the-self authentication service like Auth0 or AWS Cognito or something. Your probably don't want to implement your own user service. There are a lot of ready-made solutions out that ready for grabs (oh, the perks of micro-services)
3. forward the request to the microservice that is actually going to handle the request, so the TV series service, or the streaming service.

Note that most cloud platforms already have some service for defining API Gateways. On AWS for instance you have a service that is literally called "API Gateway" and it does all these things and many more if you configure them.

As a result a half of your application comes in the form of managed services provided by the cloud or 3rd party services that you find on the internet. You don't need to decode jwt, because it comes to you already decoded.

In the initial stage at least I don't see any problem with storing the comments and likes in the same db as you store the TV shows. Still, you don't need there anything more than just a user ID that you receive from the decoded jwt. But sure, you can store that in a separate service and a separate db as well if you like. Then you will have a table in a db that states the ID of the show, the ID of the user and the comment.

Note however that in the long run you want to keep everything "eventually consistent". So what happens if a user deletes his account? What if you delete a TV show? You probably want to trigger some events that will update the data in your comment microservice. This leads to the event-driven architecture etc.

all in all, microservices make a lot of sense, but there are a lot of ways they can communicate with each other and your data storage depends on their communication. Is it a message queue? a pipe? an event? a direct http call? do you have a sidecar for retries? all these relate to different architectures and may lead to different ways of data arrangement

Comment: This answer really helped me a lot.
I didn't think at all about the fact that the API Gateway could authenticate users, and that microservices could communicate each other to keep everything consistent.

This only was a pure theoretical question, so I didn't choose a communication layer.

Comment: The only thing I still can't understand is how can you join data, if all data is split. Let's say that we use two different services for TV shows and comments: data is consistent, but how can, for example, a TV show know what's the name of the users which commented, if it only knows their ids? Should the TV show send a direct call to the User service? Or maybe the client itself should ask the User service about the users id returned by the TV show?

Comment: well... technically you can allow the TV show service to make a call to the user service, but does it really have to? Do you need the username for any internal processing? If this is just about displaying the right usernames over the comments, then I would argue that this is not the comment service's or TV show service's responsibility to provide any user info other than the ID. The user info is not a part of their logical domain and this is only the presentation layer that needs it to display everything nicely

Comment: and if it's only the UI's requirement that it needs to know something very specific about the user, then this is the UI that should first load the comments and then issue another request to load the user info that it actually needs using a consecutive request the the user service. Now... you will notice that your UI makes 2 requests instead of one. This is very REST-y and there's nothing wrong with that, but it can also be irritating in some cases - especially if you're browsing the page from a mobile device

Comment: so this is why Facebook created GraphQL that is now opensource. So, if you build a GraphQL interface, rather than the REST interface, you can always specify in the request what info you are interested in and then it's your API Gateway that can issue a number of requests to various micro-services to collect all the data and return it in only 1 response. So now you send a request from UI saying "give me comments with usernames", GraphQL interface then first issues a request to comments service, then to user service and finally sends one response with combined data

Comment: Oh! I finally understood what GraphQL is useful for.
Anyways, isn't this process a bit slower, because needs to ask to the database which user is who by the id, without directly doing a join query like you would in a monolithic database?

Comment: i guess it depends on the data and scale. More joins = slower query. Joins are the biggest issue that's always slowing you down and if have a million users and you're executing 300 queries/sec then that one additional join will visibly slow down all of your queries, especially when you compare it to the alternative - 2 NoSQL databases. In the same time with lower load you will notice that more IO indeed requires more time and the faster query execution doesn't actually save you. But do you really care about that additional 50ms?

Comment: Then there are other cases where different pieces of data do not rely on each other and therefore can be executed in parallel